# How do I fit data points to the function e**x in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm currently trying to fit a set of data points to the function e^x. It seems that the data points are plotted fine but for whatever reason when I try to fit e^x, the result is a horizontal line. The data points are exponential. Can anyone see what might be causing this issue?

Here is some of the sample data: [csv data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yg6z4.png)

Here is the code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from math import e
import numpy as np

x_data, y_data = np.loadtxt("analog-data.csv", unpack=True, delimiter=',')

def func1(x, a, b, c):
return a + (b * (e**(c * x)))

initialGuess = [1, -1, -1]

params, params_covariance = curve_fit(func1, x_data, y_data, p0=initialGuess, absolute_sigma=True)
print(params)

plt.plot(x_data, func1(x_data, params[0], params[1], params[2]), color='orange', label='Sin Fit')
plt.plot(x_data, (y_data - func1(x_data, params[0], params[1], params[2])), 'o', color='orange')
plt.xlabel('x axis')
plt.ylabel('y axis')
plt.title('Title')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: post some samples from analog-data.csv. `pd.read_csv('analog-data.csv').head(5)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have something wrong with your 2nd plotting function. Your curve fit is on the original x and y data, but you are plotting xdata and ydata-stuff. Replace plt.plot with plt.scatter on only xdata and ydata.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from math import e
import numpy as np

x_data = np.array([500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000, 3500, 4000, 4500])
y_data = np.array([31.64, 63.20, 75.1, 84.77 , 90.82, 94.24 ,96.39 ,97.95 ,98.63])

def func1(x, a, b, c):
    return a + b*np.exp(c * x)

initialGuess = np.array([0, -1, 0])

params, params_covariance = curve_fit(func1, x_data, y_data, p0=initialGuess, absolute_sigma=True)
print(params)
# print(params_covariance)

plt.plot(x_data, func1(x_data, params[0], params[1], params[2]), color='orange', label='Sin Fit')
# plt.plot(x_data, (y_data - func1(x_data, params[0], params[1], params[2])), 'o', color='orange')
plt.scatter(x_data, y_data)
plt.xlabel('x axis')
plt.ylabel('y axis')
plt.title('Title')
plt.show()
```

[image: Output Plot]

Comment: You misspelled "choose different initial guess values". I am sure that plot is deliberate to show the difference for each data point from the fitted value.

Comment: Yea forgot to mention that OP should also pick different initial values. Also added the output of my code as an edit.

Comment: This is the main difference between their non-convergence and your convergence.